# Как в job указать название image полученного из предыдущей job в .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция

Необходимо запустить следующую job на основе image, название которой получаю из предыдущей. Т.е. заведомо знать название не удаётся, т.к. в процессе работы только получаю его. Как правильно реализовать подобный пример?

```yml
job1:
  stage: first
  script:
    - echo "my_docker_image" > myimage.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - myimage.txt

job2:
  before_script:
    - export MY_IMAGE=$(cat myimage.txt)
  image: ${MY_IMAGE}
  stage: second
  script:
    - ...
```

Comment: Если первая джоба собирает образ, то можно воспользоваться энвой. - Можете задать название образу через gitlab энву - $CI_COMMIT_SHA - она будет в каждой джобе одна и та же (в рамках одного коммита, можно ретраить пайп - энва не изменится)